# how long does an account deletion request take?

Tags: support, user-accounts, deleted-accounts

Also, is there an email confirmation of some kind that the deletion has taken place?

Would this be a total deletion of my account or are some posts/answers retained?

Comment: Don't be hasty - give it a couple of days before you decide to really do it. Decisions made in the heat of the moment are not usually good ones.

Comment: That question was a bad question for Stack Overflow. It was essentially a "can I do x or not?". It was not a specific programming question, which is why it got downvoted. Instead of getting discouraged, learn from this. You have upvoted answers on other Stack Exchange sites - why throw that away just because of this one bad experience? It takes time to learn the ropes, but it is worth it in the end.

Comment: I literally have nothing to contribute in a meaningful way, this is clear.

But, it is rather moot now, as I have sent the request in.

Comment: Well, I respectfully disagree. I hope that in time you will come back and start contributing again, as you already have.

Comment: @DamienIgoe I have to agree with Oded. It may not be easy for you to contribute if you have problems formulating your questions, but you have something to contribute. [This one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16499343/use-of-nextafterdouble-start-double-direction-in-android) for example isn't a bad question at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[All your posts are retained](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) under an anonymous user. And if you required a Stack Exchange wide deletion, that takes a Community Team member, whereas [you can do it for one site on your own](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/how-can-i-delete-my-account).

Comment: Thank you, George - I am looking for a SE wide deletion, as it is clear I have nothing worthy to contribute (I have writing difficulties and find it very hard to write in a manner that is suitable for SE).

Comment: @DamienIgoe The only way to get there is to keep trying.  Fake it till you make it.

Comment: unfortunately, my confidence in writing questions and answers here is gone, and feel that I have nothing worthwhile to contribute.  I still have heaps of questions, but as I said in a now-deleted question (where I was downvoted 5 times in about 15 minutes and spoken to sarcastically) - I'll find the information for my studies elsewhere.

Comment: @DamienIgoe - I don't know why you don't have more confidence. Your comments here are perfectly legible.

Comment: I appreciate the kind words.  But, no, my confidence has been largely erased, I  would not even know where to start wording the questions that I have (All in a field that I started teaching myself about a couple of months ago), even reading the FAQ and searching other questions - the response to my last now-deleted post was merely the icing on the cake.

I understand and accept the need for a standard of quality in posts and questions.  I can not in any way hope to match that.

I have already sent the request in, so won't be a bother anymore soon.

Comment: @DamienIgoe - I think you are giving up way too quickly. And just because you encountered **one** gruff person (perhaps they didn't get their coffee yet?) is not a good reason to quit.

Comment: @DamienIgoe A lot of people starting on the site have similar experiences. It takes some time to get a hang of what works and what doesnt. If your posts are getting downvoted stick around, lurk, vote, read some great answers, learn some new stuff, and in some time, I am sure you will yourself realise what questions work on the site.

Comment: @Damien Igoe this site infuriates me often enough - there are too many idiots chanting unhelpful mantras who couldn't write a stack switching kernel in assembler to save their lives. Unfortunately bullying is rife and I've been suspended a few times for snapping and taking out my anger and frustration on an idiot (and moderators are not immune from triggering my outrage). At the end of the day - in a few week's time - you might agree things get out of hand here.. but it's worth keeping an account around for that rare instance you need help or can actually give it.

Comment: But, as I said, I have nothing to contribute to this site.  I literally can not put most of my questions into the correct format.  (I am having the same trouble with my PhD - heavens knows how I got published).
I feel as I can not contribute effectively and efficiently, I should not be wasting people's time.

Comment: @Oded actually, it was 5 (downvoted) possibly 6, if the writer hadn't downvoted me.  It was like a pack - 5 downers in 15 minutes.  I was about to post a couple of more questions (and an answer ironically), but have thought better of it - I deleted the post (and got the 'Peer Pressure' badge - is that some kind of joke?), realising that I have nothing at all to contribute - sent the deletion request in, then posted this to find out how long the process takes.

Comment: @DamienIgoe - it was 5 downvotes on a _single_ question. And no, the badge is there to award good behavior, it is not a joke at all - you removed your unsuitable question yourself, showing you are learning to use the site. Again - I disagree that you have nothing to contribute, as your commenting here shows the opposite.

Comment: Thank you all again for your kind words, it is somewhat encouraging.  But, I don't want to take your time away from other questions - I already sent the request in before this post.  Changed my questions into Google search terms and just going about my research the 'old fashioned way'.

Comment: In respect for the members who took the time here to reach out and discuss, I will remain a member of SE.

Comment: @DamienIgoe I'm happy about that :D